# Join table in Stored Procedure using variable input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a dynamic view such that the join table can be varied depending on the input `@variable`?

For example

```
tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.@Input1 = tableB.@Input2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use dynamic SQL to do that...

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'select * from tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.'+@Input1+' = table B.'
@input2

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 T1
     JOIN Table2 T2
     ON CASE WHEN @variable = 1 THEN T1.Col1 ELSE T1.Col2 END = 
        CASE WHEN @variable = 1 THEN T2.Col1 ELSE T2.Col2 END
```

But i do not know what the performance impact would be.

Comment: Thanks jyparask, this is a more generally accepted answer which resmeble the use of If cases, but in my specific case I think sqiller answer is more sutiable.